# A qdbus command error

Tags: command-line, kde, qdbus

Why do I get an error with this command in KDE:

```
qdbus org.kde.klipper /klipper getClipboardContents
qdbus: could not exec '/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/qt5/bin/qdbus': No such file or directory
```

?

Comment: Do you have the package: qdbus-qt5 installed ? Older bug report: https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/qt4-x11/+bug/1177823

Comment: well I have installed KDE in Ubuntu 14.04. Qt Creator is also installed.

Comment: But do you have the qdbus-qt5 ? Your error message is telling that you don't have the '/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/qt5/bin/qdbus'. The '/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/qt5/bin/qdbus' is part of the qdbus-qt5. As default the KDE4 is using the libqt4-dbus. At here: breaking the installation by installing the qt5-default -> Now there is the "qdbus: could not exec '/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/qt5/bin/qdbus': No such file or directory" error. Fixing it by installing the qdbus-qt5 .

Comment: The Qt Creator installs: http://packages.ubuntu.com/trusty/qtcreator

Comment: yes installing qdbus-qt5 solved the problem. thanks.