# `qdbus` returns an error. Ubuntu 18.04

Tags: 18.04, qt, qdbus

When I run followind command: `qdbus` I get following error:

`qdbus: could not find a Qt installation of ''`

I've read alot of old questions with same error but not one helps me.

I've tried execute following commands `sudo apt-get install qt5-default` + same for for qt4, etc. but still have same error.

If any additional information required for this issue - please add comment and I'll provide info.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I've had the same issue on 18.04 server virtual machine with GUI, so I can't say whether or not it's applicable to Desktop version, but I did have to install one of the packages ( specifically `qtchooser` ) to get `qdbus`.

According to [Ubuntu package search](https://packages.ubuntu.com/search?searchon=contents&keywords=qdbus&mode=exactfilename&suite=bionic&arch=any) for bionic (18.04), these are the amd64 packages that do contain `qdbus`, among which:

- `qtchooser`
- `qdbus-qt5` ( referenced by OP on an [old post](https://askubuntu.com/questions/507555/a-qdbus-command-error?rq=1&noredirect=1#comment685314_507555) with no answer )
- `qdbus`

I'd recommend going with `sudo apt install qtchooser` since this is the  same solution I've used. However, either of these 3 should work just fine.

**Sidenote**: On Ubuntu server 18.04 with  XFCE4 installed via repositories , installing `qtchooser` produced no effect, but `qdbus-qt5` did. I suspect this has to do with certain dependencies that `qdbus-qt5` pulls with it, which may have been installed in other instances. I'd recommend installing this package.

Comment: Yep! looks like the `qdbus` program in `PATH` is a symlink to `qtchooser`. And `qtchooser` tries to run `qdbus` in the preferenced QT installation. Without `qdbus-qt5`, there is no corresponding `qdbus` program for the qt5 installation.

Comment: @Winny Oh, wow ! Kudos for pointing that out. I did not realize or checked before that it is a symlink !

Comment: on 20.04 had to install both qtchooser qdbus-qt5, thx!