# How to check whether module is loaded with custom configurations?

Tags: networking, drivers, configuration, system

In the answer by [Chili555](https://askubuntu.com/users/19421/chili555)  for [How do I create a system file /etc/modprobe.d/ath9k.conf?](https://askubuntu.com/q/440256/295286) it is shown that you can create a config file for a kernel module . Now the question is how do I verify that the options set in that config file have taken effect after `sudo modprobe ath9k` ?

Specific option that I am trying to check is `ps_enable`. However,  doing the following

```
$ modinfo ath9k | grep ps_enable
parm:           ps_enable:Enable WLAN PowerSave (int)
```

only explains what the parameter is and not its current value.

Answer (score 5):

**TL;DR**: Look in `/sys/module/ath9k/parameters/` or do `cat  "$(readlink -f /sys/class/net/wlp2s0/device/driver/)"/module/parameters/<param_name>`

Apparently such information is contained within `/sys` filesystem. According to [Gilles's answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/7881) on the relevant post, in order to find the driver in use by interface you would execute

```
readlink /sys/class/net/wlan0/device/driver
```

which would provide the relative path as in

```
../../../../bus/pci/drivers/ath5k
```

In my case due to [systemd and predictive interface naming](https://askubuntu.com/a/704364/295286), the interface is named differently and produces

```
$  readlink /sys/class/net/wlp2s0/device/driver
../../../../bus/pci/drivers/ath9k
```

The resulting directory path contains subdirectories `module/parameters/` where there will be files for each parameter containing their current value. Thus, if I edit the `/etc/modprobe/ath9k.conf` file and reinsert the module, the result is as follows:

```
# After editing the conf file to set parameter to 1
$ sudo sh -c 'modprobe -r ath9k ; sleep 3; modprobe ath9k'
$ sudo cat  /sys/class/net/wlp2s0/device/driver/../../../../bus/pci/drivers/ath9k/module/parameters/ps_enable
1
# after editing the file and setting parameter to 0
$ sudo sh -c 'modprobe -r ath9k ; sleep 3; modprobe ath9k'
$ sudo cat  /sys/class/net/wlp2s0/device/driver/../../../../bus/pci/drivers/ath9k/module/parameters/ps_enable
0
```

The command can be combined as well.

```
$ cat  "$(readlink -f /sys/class/net/wlp2s0/device/driver/)"/module/parameters/ps_enable
0
```

---

Alternative `/sys` path would also be  `/sys/modules` and probably more preferable if you already know what driver is used by the interface, so you can skip the `readlink` part. In my specific case

```
/sys/module/ath9k/parameters/ps_enable
```

or

```
/sys/module/ath9k/drivers/pci\:ath9k/module/parameters/
```

According to `sysfs(5)` manual, "This  subdirectory  contains one subdirectory for each module that is loaded into the kernel."

---

There's also another way to figure out what driver is in use by the interface (if necessary, although the fact that I'm editing conf file for the module means I already know what module the interface uses; but in case you do need that I'll leave it as an alternative). If you do have desktop environment and `dbus` running, as well as [`qdbus`](https://askubuntu.com/a/1102285/295286) or `dbus-send` installed, such information can be queried via Network Manager's dbus interface ( though it requires figuring out the object path of each individual device, and probably would be better written in Python or C )

```
$ qdbus --system org.freedesktop.NetworkManager /org/freedesktop/NetworkManager/Devices/14 org.freedesktop.NetworkManager.Device.Driver
ath9k
```