# Wifi holds for a few minutes and then drops or simply doesn't connect

Tags: wireless, lubuntu, internet

I've been having issues with wifi dropping randomly. This wasn't a problem until around 2 months after I switched from Windows to Lubuntu. Now I'm even having issues with my wifi not connecting even on startup. I get getting "interface doesnt support scanning". Acer es1-531-c97t

Comment: In order to be of much help we need to know what wifi card you have?

Comment: Ethernet controller: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. RTL8111/8168/8411 PCI Express Gigabit Ethernet Controller

Comment: hey i have that wifi card! (I also had a hella time getting it to work) can you post output from dmesg, and lsmod?  my wifi adapter wouldnt work unitll i disabled secureboot in the bios, and black listed "ideapad_lenovo" in /etc/modprobe.d/blacklist.conf ... Im not sure if  this would apply to you, or if you have that module. what kind of computer is it?

see this post: 
https://askubuntu.com/questions/1130048/how-are-modules-assigned-and-how-would-you-troubleshoot-modules?noredirect=1#comment1871639_1130048

Comment: RTL8111/8168/8411 PCI Express Gigabit Ethernet Controller is ethernet, not wifi

Comment: j0h I have no way of getting wifi right now so I can't copy and paste an output at the moment. And Jeremy31 I'm aware but I can't seem to find my wifi card through the terminal. Might have to switch back to windows soon.

Comment: @NickWhite Please see the following question and follow the instructions to provide the information we need to help you. If you don't have WIFI then copy it to a thumb drive. Thanks! https://askubuntu.com/questions/425155/my-wireless-wifi-connection-does-not-work-what-information-is-needed-to-diagnos?noredirect=1&lq=1